# What are the conditions to compose limits to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I've recently become a little obsessed with all the ways limits can be composed - and the preconditions for this to take place. I took $A,B_{1},B_{2},C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\to B_{1},\ g:B_{2} \to C$ and further assumed $f[A] \subseteq B_{2}$. And then I listed out all the ways to compose $f$ and $g$ with limits:

\begin{align}
1.&&\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b,\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=c&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=c \\\\ 2.&&\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b,\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=\infty&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=\infty \\\\ 3.&&\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty,\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=c&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=c \\\\ 4.&&\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty,\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=\infty \\\\ 5.&&\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=b,\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=c&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to\infty}g(f(x))=c \\\\ 6.&&\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=b,\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=\infty&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to\infty}g(f(x))=\infty \\\\ 7.&&\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty,\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=c&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to\infty}g(f(x))=c \\\\ 8.&&\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty,\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty&&\implies&&\lim_{x\to\infty}g(f(x))=\infty
\end{align}

and I got the proofs (and preconditions) for $1$ through $5$.

For example, for $1.$ we need *either*:

- $A\ $:  $g(b)=c$, *or*
- $B\ $:  $\exists \delta>0,\forall x \in A: \ \ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-b|>0$

For $2.$ we need $B$

For $3.$ no additional requirements are needed

For $4.$ no additional requirements are needed

For $5.$ we need $A$

But now I am stuck on $6$. So far I have the following:

---

I expand the definitions of what I have, and am trying to prove.

\begin{align}
1: &&& \lim_{ x \to \infty } f(x) = b &&\iff&& \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists c \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in A: \ \ x>c \implies |f(x)-b| < \varepsilon \\\\
2: &&& \lim_{ x \to b } g(x) = \infty &&\iff&& \forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \exists\delta>0,\forall x \in B_{2}: \ \ 0<|x-b| < \delta \implies g(x) > r \\\\
\text{Aim for:} &&& \lim_{ x \to \infty } g(f(x)) = \infty &&\iff&& \forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \exists c \in \mathbb{R},\forall x \in A: \ \ x>c \implies g(f(x)) > r
\end{align}

Then take arbitrary $R \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $\exists\delta>0,\forall x \in B_{2}: \ \ 0<|x-b| < \delta \implies g(x) > R$. Take particular $D>0$ for which that is true. Therefore, $\forall x \in B_{2}: \ \ 0<|x-b| < D \implies g(x) > R$. Since $D>0$, we also have $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in A: \ \ x>c \implies |f(x)-b| < D$. Take particular $C \in \mathbb{R}$ for which this is true. Therefore, $\forall x \in A: \ \ x>C \implies |f(x)-b| < D$. Take arbitrary $X \in A$. Therefore, $X>C \implies |f(X)-b| < D$. Since $f(X) \in B_{2}$, we get $0<|f(X)-b| < D \implies g(f(X)) > R$.
Assume $X>C$, therefore $|f(X)-b| < D$. ***Assume precondition*** $b \not\in f[A]$. Therefore $|f(X)-b| > 0$. Therefore $0<|f(X)-b| < D$, which implies $g(f(X)) > R$. Hence we have the implication  $X>C \implies g(f(X)) > R$. $X$ is arbitrary, $C$ is particular, $R$ is arbitrary, therefore we have $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \exists c \in \mathbb{R},\forall x \in A: \ \ x>c \implies g(f(x)) > r$.

---

That proof works if I assume $b \not\in f[A]$, which seems to make sense as a precondition. If I take an example of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=-\ln(x)$, then indeed $0 \notin f[A]$, and it looks like $g(f(x)) \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$:
[image]

But then that got me thinking, is there any preconditions weaker than this? Surely if I can find examples that fail this condition, then it its stronger than it needs to be. So what if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin(x)$? Then not only $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$, but also $0 \in f[A]$. And then what if $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$? Then $g(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$. And it *looks* like $g(f(x)) \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$:
[image]

But if I think about it, $g(0)$ is undefined, so $0 \not\in B_{2}$. If we still maintain that $0 \in f[A]$, then $f[A] \not\subseteq B_{2}$. The only way to *maintain* that $f[A] \subseteq B_{2}$ is to say $0 \not\in f[A]$, so the precondition I came up with seems to apply to this example too.

Is $b \not\in f[A]$ the minimal precondition for composition $6.$ to take place?

---

***EDIT:*** Thanks to [Karl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/279914/karl) for pointing out that a precondition weaker than $f(x) \neq c$ is:

- $B\ '\ $:  $\exists c \in\mathbb{R}, \forall x \in A: x>c \implies |f(x)-c|>0$

And thanks to [David K](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/139123/david-k) for showing me that $B\ '$ is also a sufficient condition for $5.$ :)

Comment: For #1, consider $f(x)=3,$ $g(x)=17$ when $x\neq3,$ $g(3)=0.$ Then $\lim_{x\to b} g(x)=17$ but $g\circ f(x)=0$ everywhere and therefore $\lim_{x\to a} g\circ f(x)=0.$ I think you not only need something like $b\not\in f[A]$ in #6 but also in some of your earlier examples. But I think you can weaken the condition so that it only says there is some neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $b\not\in f[I].$

Comment: I know. I'm saying that I think I got the preconditions for examples #1 through #5 down. I'm stuck on #6. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: There are two cases. If $g(b)$ is not defined, then you need $b\notin f[A]$ in order for $g\circ f$ to be defined. If $g(b)$ is defined, then you just need $f$ to *eventually* stop attaining the value $b$, i.e. $\exists n,\forall x>n,f(x)\ne b.$

Comment: In fact, I think all of your cases will boil down to some form of "either $g$ is continuous at $f(a)$, or there is a neighborhood of $a$ on which $f$ does not attain the value $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$".

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: Also BTW, although "$g\circ f(x)$" is unambiguous in context, I'd probably write it $g(f(x))$ or $(g\circ f)(x)$.

Comment: @Karl fixed the $g \circ f(x)$ thing

Comment: OK, I see what you meant in the original version of the question about what you had done. It's a lot clearer now that you've explicitly and specifically listed each precondition.

Comment: @Karl It seems to me the case where $g(b)$ is not defined is ruled out by the assumption that $f[A]\subseteq B_2,$ if I am interpreting the notation $g:B_2\to C$ correctly.

Comment: I think #5 is true if either of the conditions $A$ or $B$ is true; #6 needs $B$ because $A$ never true; and the last two don't need any conditions other than the initial assumptions. Your condition $B$ is the kind of "weakening" of the condition $b\not\in F[A]$ that I had in mind, only you did it better (because you only need a punctured neighborhood, as you wrote, not an interval as I suggested).

Comment: @Karl Yeah I think what you suggested, i.e. $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in A: \ \ x>c \implies |f(x)-b|>0$, should be the broadest condition. If $b \notin f[A]$ then it is satisfied by picking any real number. If $b \notin B_2$ then $b \notin f[A]$ so it is satisfied. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidK I can see how #5 can satisfy A as a minimal precondition. But why would #5 satisfying B do anything? In #5, $f(x) \to b$ as $x \to \infty$; while B is concerned with $f(x)$ never taking on the value $b$ near $a$ - but $a$ doesn't appear in #5. It doesn't quite click for me what B would help us with.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about neighborhoods in a more general way (where you can have a neighborhood of $\infty$) and neglected the specific language of $B$. Indeed you need a different formulation, something like $B':\exists N,\forall x \in A: x>N \implies |f(x)-b|>0.$ By the way, $f(x)\neq b$ is a slightly more concise (and I think more to-the-point) way of saying $|f(x)-b|>0.$

Comment: @DavidK AHHH, I see what you mean. Rather than B, you meant that "∃c∈R,∀x∈A:  x>c⟹|f(x)−b|>0" could be used to satisfy both #5 and #6. Just did a quick proof, and indeed that is true. Thanks :)

And yes, I understand $f(x) \neq b \iff |f(x) -b| > 0$, I was just being lazy for the sake of my proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general intuition behind all of these compositions of limits is that as the input of $f$ approaches a limit $L_1$ (which I'm using merely as a symbol to represent either the finite or infinite limit), the first limit statement says the output of $f$ approaches a limit $L_2$,
which means the input of $g$ also approaches $L_2$, and then the second limit statement says the output of $g$ approaches a limit $L_3.$
The reason why you need extra conditions in many of your cases -- and the principle that will tell when the extra conditions are required -- is that there's a small hole in that intuitive argument.
(Or one might say that there is **not** a hole where we need one, but that's using the word "hole" in a completely different way.)

The general idea of all of the formulas for limits of $f(x)$ in your examples
is that there is a limit point of the input ($a$ or $\infty$) and a limit point of the output ($b$ or $\infty$).
We use a parameter $\delta$ to define a family of ever-shrinking *punctured neighborhoods* of the limit point of the input.
Many people prefer to call the parameter $N$ when the limit point is $\infty$.
For a finite limit point this punctured neighborhood looks like
$\{x \mid 0 < \lvert x - a \rvert < \delta\},$
whereas for the limit $\infty$ the it looks like $\{x \mid x > N\}.$

The idea is that for any $x$ in the neighborhood we can use the parameter $\delta$ or $N$ to shrink the punctured neighborhood so much that we get a punctured neighborhood that doesn't contain $x.$ You can imagine changing the parameter continually so that there's no $x$ that remains in the neighborhood forever; like in the TV program Survivor, we keep voting people off the island, except that unlike the show, **everyone** eventually gets voted off.

What gives us a limit is that as we shrink the punctured neighborhood of the input of $f,$ we are guaranteed that we can identify an ever-shrinking sequence of neighborhoods of the limit point of the output, and every point $y$ in one of these neighborhoods except for the limit point eventually gets "shrunk out" of the neighborhood
(or "voted off the island").

The limits for $g$ have a similar meaning, just with (possibly) different limit points for the input and output.

But here's the rub: for the input of $g$, we need an ever-shrinking punctured neighborhood,
but the output of $f$ is only guaranteed to give us ever-shrinking **non**-punctured neighborhoods.
There's nothing in the standard definition of the limit that says if the limit of $f(x)$ is $b$ then $f(x)$ cannot actually be **equal** to $b$ for as long and as often as it likes.

There are two ways to plug this logical hole: make $g$ continuous at the limit point of $f$, so that repeated visits by $f$ to that exact point don't prevent $g$'s output neighborhoods from shrinking the way they ought to;
or make sure that $f$'s output is never $b$, or at least that once we have shrunk its input's neighborhood enough, the output of $f$ will never be $b$,
so that after that point $g$ always gets the punctured neighborhood that it needs for its input.

The first approach (your condition $A$) fills a possible "hole" in $g$'s definition;
the second approach (your condition $B$, or a related condition for cases where $x\to\infty$) **makes** a "hole" in $f$'s definition by puncturing all of its output neighborhoods after some point in the limit process.

Your condition $A$ is the first approach; condition $B$ is the second approach for the cases where $x\to a$, and there is a related condition that provides the second approach in cases where $x\to\infty$:

$$ \exists N\,\forall x \in A: x>N \implies f(x)\neq b. $$

You are going to need at least the first or second condition to be true in every single case of limits of the composition of functions.
The only times when you do not have to mention a condition are due to the fact that sometimes a condition is always satisfied for that example or is never satisfied for that example.

In cases where the limit of $f$ is $\infty,$ its output neighborhood is always punctured, that is, condition $B$ (or its counterpart for the case $x\to\infty$)
is always satisfied, and therefore you don't need to mention any conditions at all.

In every other case where $g$ goes to $\infty$, it is impossible to satisfy condition $A$ and therefore you **must** satisfy condition $B$.

In the remaining cases, where both limits are finite, you need to say that at least one of $A$ or $B$ is true, because neither is automatically true but either is possible.

This is easily extended to cover cases where the limit is $-\infty.$